# Access variable from another function in same file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a problem. I want that in a function a variable is set and that is exported by another function as i don't want to return that variable at the invocation of function. How can i do this. Code look like this.

```
var details = {};
   module.exports.set = function (var1){ 
   details.n = var1;
}
module.exports.m = details.n;
```

But `details.n` is returning undefined. I know it is because of `var details = {}`. Then how can i resolve my purpose. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, tried and tested

```
module.exports.set = function (var1) {
    module.exports.m = var1;
};
```

Now you can call set with anything and it will be set in 'm'

```
var test = require('./test');
test.set('test123');
console.log(test.m);
test.set('test1234');
console.log(test.m);
test.set(function() {});
console.log(test.m);
```

OUTPUT:

```
test123
test1234
[Function]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should export `details` instead of `details.n`

```
module.exports.m = details;
```

This allow you to get the reference of `details` using `import`. Exporting `details.n` will get you only the initial value, updates won't get reflected.

Comment: Can you add little more about import with code? @ArunGhosh